# Token transfer on rinkeby by myetherwallet fail

Tags: rinkeby

I try to transfer erc20 token I made on rinkeby by myethereallet
Finally it says
Error transaction was not mined with 750 seconds please make sure your transaction was properly sent.
Whether my token created is wrong or the rinkeby wrong?

Comment: What is the token source code? That error message might appear when your gas price is too low.